# JQuery Selector on Dynamically Added Element

Tags: jquery, selector

I can't figure out how to coax JQuery in to selecting an element (not binding handlers) that is dynamically inserted in to the DOM after the page loads.

For example:

If I have HTML:

```
<div id="bar">
 World!
</div>
```

Then I create a new element and insert it in to DOM:

```
var foo = '<div id="foo">Hello</div>';
$("#bar").before(foo);
```

I end up with this:

```
<div id="foo">Hello</div>
<div id="bar">
 World!
</div>
```

Later on I might want to do something different with the element I inserted, using JQuery to manipulate that new element. But if I try to do:

```
myHappyEl = $("#foo");
```

Then myHappyEl will be undefined. JQuery doesn't see it, presumably because it go attached after DOM was loaded.

I've seen lots of suggestions addressing a possibly related but subtly different issue, wherein the solution is to use .live()/.on() to attach an event listener when an element comes in to being. That would be brilliant if I wanted to capture a click event or something, but I don't; I want to be able to select the dynamically added element(s).

Comment: How about pushibng a reference into an array of every element that you create and insert?

Comment: Seems ok http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xd4/

Comment: _"after jQuery was done watching for such things"_ - No, jQuery doesn't watch for element creation at all. When you pass a selector to _$()_ like in your _$("#foo")_ example jQuery looks for the element(s) that match at that moment.

Comment: Indeed, it is Ok. The problem was that $("#bar").before(foo); was being executed by a event handler. Thus, myHappyEl = $("#foo"); was being executed before the event had been completely handlend (because of a database access).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to assign that variable after the element has been inserted, like so:

```
var myHappyEl = $("#foo"); //Nothing, it isnt there
var foo = '<div id="foo">Hello</div>';
$("#bar").before($(foo));
myHappyEl = $("#foo");
```

Otherwise, the element doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what's happening here? I don't understand the $(foo) part in particular.

Comment: @kburlz -- `foo` is just a string of HTML - the `$(foo)` wraps that HTML string and creates a jQuery element.